# Rapository can not connect to Postgres (testcontainers) in integration tests with KafkaListener

Tags: apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I run integrations tests using test containers with Postgres DB. When I send json message to a kafka topic using KafkaTemplate I getting SQL exception:

```
[W] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01 
[E] SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: relation "test_db.test_schema" does not exist

could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

My test looks like this:

```
@Autowired
TestRepository repository;

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

private void publishFile(String fileName) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("test.topic", "1", readFile(fileName));
}

@Test
public void test_1() {
    publishFile("json/test_1.json");
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(()-> repository.findAll().size() == 1);
}
```

When I call publishFile message arrives to a @KafkaListener

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test.topic")
public void onRecieve(@Payload String json, @Header(name = RECIEVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
    TestEntity entity = mapper.readValue(json, TestEntity.class);
    repository.save(entity);
}
```

But when I use repository directly in test like this:

```
@Test
public void test_1() {
    repository.findAll();
}
```

Everything ok. I can write to and read from repository.

Also I have access to a repository in this test:

```
@Test
public void test_1() {
    TestEntity entity = mapper.readValue(readFile("json/test_1.json"), TestEntity.class);
    repository.save(entity);
    publishFile("json/test_1.json");
    log.info(repository.findAll());
    await().atMost(5, SECONDS).until(()-> repository.findAll().size() == 1);
}
```

In main thread I can write to a repository and after sendig message to a @KafkaListener I can read from repository. But In @KafkaListener thread I can not. I suppose there should be the same test context but looks like its not. How can I use repository to interract with Postgres container in @KafkaListener thread?